# Meaning of the "Ni Naru" in this phrase

Tags: meaning, translation, phrases, japanese-to-english, learning

> 14年前に秋葉原で7人が殺された事件　男が死刑になる

Does anyone know what's the translation? i'm unable to translation because of "ni naru". i know "ni naru + noun" means "to became", but i don't understand your meaning in the phrase.

Answer (score 2):

As you understand, it is the same *to become*. Of course, *the man became a death sentence* is not idiomatic in English, but the Japanese になる can work that way. The preceding noun can be what *happens* to the subject.

Another example is

- 彼は解雇になった He got fired (literally: He became an unemployment).